# Image series bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have for example image of Coin. 
[image]

I want to give a value from 0 to example 20.

```
0: no coin
1: to one coin
2: 2 coin etc
20: 20 coin
```

The collection of 6 coins should looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Hi to you. To help you we need more informations, like what you need to do, how you want it and what you know

Comment: OK, I have a database with results and I want to show the results as coins. I work on PHP so I want to pass value from PHP that comes from the DATABASE and pass them, the only thing I found is rating system RATY JQuery where I can change the star images with coins, but it wont work. Therefore I was stucked here to here some body maybe have tried it before to get some inspiration. Thx alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you prefer pure JS:

```js
var maxI = Math.floor(Math.random() * (21 - 1)) + 1;
var marginCoins = 0;
var coin = [];
for (var i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
 coin[i] = document.createElement('img');
 coin[i].src = 'http://placehold.it/75x75';
 coin[i].style.position = 'fixed';
 coin[i].style.top = marginCoins+'px';
 coin[i].style.height = '75px';
 coin[i].style.border = '1px solid black';
 document.body.appendChild(coin[i]);
 marginCoins += 45;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was fetching after, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".coins").each(function(){
    
    var $self = $(this);
    
    var applyCoins = function(){
        $self.empty();
        var coins = $self.data("coins");
        for (var i=coins-1; i>=0; i--) {
            var $coin = $("<div></div>").addClass("coin").css("top", (i*20)+"px");
            $self.append($coin);
        }
    };
    
    $self.on("loadCoins", function(){
        applyCoins();
    });
    
    applyCoins();
});

$("#button").click(function(){
    $(".coins").data("coins", $("#input").val()).trigger("loadCoins");
});
```

```css
.coins {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}

.coins .coin {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" value="3" id="input" />
  <input type="button" value="change" id="button" />
</p>
<div class="coins" data-coins="10"></div>
```